# How many combination to choose k out of n with recursion - wrong answer help

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

How many combinations of choosing $k$ numbers out of $\{1,2...,n\}$ so there are no consecutive numbers in a group, example: $\{1,4,9\}$. Find a recursion formula for $n\geq 0, k\geq0$.

I was thinking about $n\cdot F(n-3,k-1)$, means we have $n$ numbers to choose at first and then have to choose another $k-1$ out of the remaining $n-3$ (when taking off the chosen and it's consecutives), But might need times $n!$.

Would love if someone can explain what is wrong in this solution.

Thank you.

---

Also might need to break it apart to inner chosen numbers and numbers on edges like $1$ and $n$

Comment: If you chose $n$ as your original number from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ then are there really only $n-3$ numbers left to choose from for the next number?  You aren't allowed to pick $n$ again, and you aren't allowed to pick $n-1$ since that is next to it... but what is the third illegal choice?  $n+1$?  We weren't allowed to pick $n+1$ to begin with anyways since it was out of bounds.  Similarly for if we picked $1$ to start.

Comment: Further, if you pick a number from the middle first, then you now have "four boundary" numbers rather than just the original two.  Finally... you should clarify whether we are considering *sequences* of choices where order of selection matters, or if we are merely counting *sets* of numbers where the order of selection does not matter.  Your attempt so far seems to assume that order matters but from the problem description I would have assumed otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, so because the solution conditions are changing in every step it is not a proper recursion? like you said, creating 2 more boundaries every step when choosing in the middle.

Comment: Oh, you could still do it with recursion... it would get rather messy though.  Also, you really should first answer the request for clarification on whether or not order matters.  The much smarter and easier answer that I can see at a glance is to treat order as irrelevant (*and multiply by $k!$ at the end if order is supposed to be relevant*) and use a stars-and-bars style argument by looking at the respective distances between entries and the boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not quite right because of two reasons:

- If a middle number is picked, then three numbers are excluded. If an end number, $1$ or $n$, is picked, then only two numbers are excluded. So it is not always $n-3$.
- Taking a number from the middle destroys the non-consecutive condition. If take $5$, then what remains is e.g. $\{1,2,3,7,8,9\}$, but now it is OK to contain both $3$ and $7$, even though they are ordered next to each other.

---

**Hint:**

If $n$ is not in the set, you have a non-consecutive subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ of size $k$.

If $n$ is in the set, everything else is a non-consecutive subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}$ of size $k-1$.